Databricks Workflow Output in Data Factory
I have seen a lot of articles explaining how to return the output from a databricks notebook in Data Factory. Is it possible to do this from a workflow?
I am new to Databricks, but the project I am working on calls a series of Databricks notebooks from ADF, every call is done via a databricks workflow, so notebooks are never called directly.
Essentially, this is what is happening now -

Pipeline calls workflow and waits
Workflow triggers a notebook
Notebook code executes (python), returns a value with this code - dbutils.notebook.exit('test')
Pipeline tries to get the output and fails with this error - "cannot be evaluated because property 'runOutput' doesn't exist"


This is possible but since there are multiple tasks, the solution is a bit more complicated.
The process should be as follows :

Pipeline calls workflow and waits
Workflow triggers a notebook
Notebook code executes (python), returns a value with this code - dbutils.notebook.exit('test')
Workflow may have another task which triggers the same or another notebook
Notebook 2 code executes (python), returns a value with this code - dbutils.notebook.exit('test2')
Pipeline gets the result using the jobs/runs/get API call. This will contain an array called “tasks” within which there will be multiple unique run_id, 1 for each task.
Pipeline needs to loop through each task runid to get the individual outputs. You would use jobs/runs/get-output with run_id as a parameter. The run_id should be that of the task and not the job itself.


Hi, thanks for the response. What is the purpose of steps 4 and 5? Does there have to be 2 tasks (e.g. 2 notebook calls) for the 'tasks' array to be retrievable in ADF?

The 2 tasks are just to illustrate that it possible to retrieve the output of multiple tasks. For your use case you can leave steps 4 and 5
